# Larger circuit design for same boolean function?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I've designed this circuit with 4 logic gates, and did Karnaugh map's simplification and Quine McCluskey method. However I found out that actually my circuit design is already *optimized* and I can't really compare how the simplifications offer a less expensive circuit.

[image: This is the original circuit]

I'd like to add a few more gates to the circuit not changing the boolean function of it. Which is (X2'∙X0)+(X2∙X1)

Comment: Are you saying something like add inverters to the inputs and outputs of the middle "AND" gate and "OR" gate and then redo the work?

Comment: Aha ... I just need to make a bigger circuit to show how Quine McCluskey help to get a shorter funcion and so a smaller circuit

Comment: Your current circuit is prone to logical hazards. Do you know what a consensus term is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in your desire to add extra gates, because as it's currently constructed it is prone to a logical hazard. Particularly there is a risk of the output briefly transitioning to a $0$ when the input changes between $111$ and $011$ when it should remain $1$.

Adding the term $X_0X_1$ will not change the logical function of the circuit, and will eliminate the hazard. So your expression will become:

$$F=X_0X_2'+X_1X_2+X_0X_1$$